# Firebird .NET provider and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, firebird

I have no problems setting up a regular (Windows Forms or Console) project in C# to use Firebird's .NET data provider.

However, whenever I try to use the same provider in ASP.NET I do the following:

1. Copy the DLL to the project to keep it under version control
2. Add the reference to the project
3. Create an entry in `<connectionStrings/>` tag for my connection.
4. Try to use the entry to connect to Firebird

Here is the entry example:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add 
       name="cstringdbname"
       connectionString="User=SYSDBA;Password=MY_PASS;Database=/opt/interbase/data/mydbname;Server=MyHostName; Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true" 
       providerName="Firebird"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I tried with different stuff in `providerName` attribute. Nothing seems to work.

My problem is in step #4. Whenever I try connecting to the Database with a SqlDataSource component, the connection attempts to use SQLServer data provider instead of Firebird's, and I get an error.

My question: is there anything else I need to do in order to make ASP.NET to load, use, acknwoledges the existance of my Firebird provider?

Comment: Show some sample code for <connectionString /> and reading the connection string/creating the connection in the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did to get it to work:

- Changed the web config adding these entries:

First, a new DBProviderFactory under `configuration` tag:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
      <add 
          name="Firebird Data Provider"
          invariant="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient" description="Firebird"
          type="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FirebirdClientFactory, FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"
      />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Second, my connection string entry looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add 
   name="rshkdb"
   connectionString="User=u;Password=p;Database=/mydb;Server=X.X.X.X; Connection lifetime=15;Pooling=true"
/>
</connectionStrings>
```

- Added the Firebird's client DLL to the project's references using **Copy Local** option to **true**. This is very important, otherwise, ASP.NET won't find the library at runtime (only at compile time).

Answer (score 1):

I too tried this in a past project and didn't get it to work.  However, I only found the connection string to matter, so I moved the setting to the appSettings section.  Once you do this, you can use the same connection settings that you used for your WinApp projects.